# blinking light in python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to have a light which will light up at specific times given to it by a list. What I have right now puts a keyframe at 0 right before, then goes up to max at the time given, then interpolate back to 0 a constant time later.

The problem is, I want it to be so that if I have multiple blink times in a short period it adds on - right now it sort of "overwrites" it. To be clear, if I have 2 times close to each other, I want it to do it's thing for the first time, and then from wherever it is in the interpolation back to 0 it goes from /that/ value back to the max value. As I have it now, it interpolates to 0 right before the second time.

Hope I made myself clear! This is my current script:

`def blink(mat,t,len,b):#Assuming material already has an emit node
    mat.use_nodes=True
    n=mat.node_tree.nodes
    out=n.get('Material Output')
    emit=n.get('Emission')
    emit.inputs[1].default_value=0
    emit.inputs[1].keyframe_insert(data_path='default_value',frame=t-1)
    emit.inputs[1].default_value=b
    emit.inputs[1].keyframe_insert(data_path='default_value',frame=t+1)
    emit.inputs[1].default_value=0
    emit.inputs[1].keyframe_insert(data_path='default_value',frame=t+len)`

Comment: Hi. Please add some of your code to the question so someone trying to answer doesn't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Is there any reason it has to be Python-based?  The only reason I ask is because you could keyframe this with Constant interpolation, and have it cycle as many times as you'd like using an F-curve modifier:https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fmodifiers.html

Comment: I mean this is supposed to represent data I have, so it'd take a while to do by hand. I'm not quite sure what you mean by cycle using an F-Curve?? Is that something I can automate?